# How do I package .NET with my program?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation

I have a program that is being deployed to a computer without .NET and without any possibility of an internet connection. How do I make my install project include the .NET framework (up to 4.0)?

Comment: Assuming VSI, see [this mkb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create my deployment projects from inside VS, to do so you need to add a Setup Project to your solution:

[image: New project window]

Once you add the release output from your main project/projects :

Go to the `setup project properties -> Prerequisites`  set the prerequisites to download from the same location as the installer

[image: Prerequisites setup]

**Note :** if you are deploying to Windows XP some of machines (the unpatched ones will require the [WIC components](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=32) to be installed as well as Windows Installer ( version 3 or 4, I'm not sure)) before the .Net framework.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [standalone installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718).